# Is there regular maintenance that can be done to help maintain open kitchen drain lines?

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink, drains

Is there regular maintenance that can be done to help maintain clean kitchen drain lines?

In this case, there is a disposal, but only used for residue as most everything goes into the trash. Nothing bad (like grease) is ever put down the drain. But ever year or two, the 2" lines fill with looks like crisco! Arteriosclerosis!

Is it worth it to put liquid drain cleaner or something like that down there once a month to be proactive about clogged drains?

Comment: That crisco is sure sounds like grease. Do you ever run hot soapy water down the drain. Do you allow it to run a short while after you are done grinding? Where is it plugging, in the trap?

Comment: You could pour a pot of boiling water down them every month.  Make pasta first.

Comment: @Gil - no grease except maybe minimal amount rinsed off plates. The trap is fine. It's the line off the trap going to the main that gets clogged.

Comment: Wilik has the right answer!

Comment: @Willk - your comment should be re-written as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Willk - your comment should be re-written as an answer. – Greg Nickoloff

Ok Greg.

---

**You could pour a pot of boiling water down them every month. Make pasta first.**

I am pretty sure this helps my drains.  I am careful about grease but not super careful.

I put it down as a comment because who does not do that?  Then I realized not everyone makes their coffee with boiling water from a saucepan, and has extra water.  Some people eat those premade mac and cheeses that don't require boiling water (they are good, too).  Some people boil water to make soup but when they pour what they cant finish down the drain, it is cool.  Maybe some people never have occasion to pour a pot of boiling water down the drain?

Boiling water has a lot of energy in it.  It will cut grease.  It makes things clean.  Plus it is super cheap.  If you try it and it does not work, you will not have wasted money or damaged anything.